# Error HTTP500 when trying to show all product on product list

Tags: magento2, http-error-500

I have a problem with magento 2.4.0.
When i'm trying to display all products in products grid, system shows me HTTP 500 ERROR

[image: Error shows when I select All]

Error shows when I select All

**UPDATE**

The same error is When I try trying search only selected products.

In var/log/nginx

`2894781#2894781: *824530 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 48238592 bytes) in /var/www/html/mystore/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php on line 24" while reading response header from upstream, client: 185.28.212.123, server: mystore.com, request: "GET /catalogsearch/result/?q=Ramiz+edukacyjna+skarbonka+-+bankomat+na+polskie+nomina%C5%82y+dla+dzieci HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "mystore.com", referrer: "https://mystore.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=ramiz"`

In php.ini i set up memory_limit on 4G

Something usage a lot of memory but i don't know what?

We added about 40 new products with a lot of configurations (variants) and name is "Raimz ..." . Do you think this caused this problem?

Before change index in ElasticSearch, after type keyword "Ramiz" website return error 500, when i execute command `bin/magento indexer:reindex` website is temporary working, but error coming back after a few querries in search .

When I change Index in ElasticSearch, after type keyword "Ramiz" is displayed notice "Not found items"

After changing index in elasticsearch I executed command `bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please check the error logs or enable developer mode to see the exact error.

Comment: In exception.log there is no errors :/ When i select All, website is loading a long time and next there is HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: I have also beta version and there is everything ok. Do you think would it problem with permissions?

Comment: Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sovled this problem. It was problem with elastiserch. I had too little RAM memory in my server. When I configure elasticsearch in new serwer, problem with Error 500 was Solved